# Noise on CCSprite

Tags: ios4, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, object-code

I made my project to show simple texture by using CCSprite.

But I found that the texture contains some tiny noise , black pixel bug.

I divided the png file into small piece by using code. And add it to the mainview.

Not all of them have noise, But some of them have it.

I can't know the reason.

Please send your opinion.

```
CCSprite *sprite = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name] rect:CGRectMake(startx, starty, w, h)] retain];

float drawX = x, drawY = y;

CGSize size = [sprite contentSize];

int nWidth = size.width;

int nHeight = size.height;

nWidth *= scale;

nHeight *= scale;

drawX = drawX + nWidth/2;

drawY = drawY - nHeight/2;

ConvertCoordf(&drawX, &drawY);

drawY -= nHeight;

[sprite setScale:scale];

[sprite setPosition:ccp(drawX, drawY)];

[_mainLayer addChild:sprite];

[sprite release];
```

Comment: a working solution to this problem is to use TexturePacker

Comment: Can you post your png? I would like to test this a bit.. this could be some kind of problem on your image encoding or on the current opengl texture context...

Answer (score 0):

For every image, it has some noise pixel around it (Only 1 pixel). For example, if you want to include an image with 30px*30px, you'd better make it into a 31px*31px image and put your image in the middle of it.In other words, surround your image with 1px.